# Wordpress SQL JOIN query

Tags: php, wp-query, wpdb, sql, join-tables

**Hi**
Im trying to run 2 querys in the same query call.

```
        // send the query

global $wpdb;
$commentQ = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments " . $whereClause . $orderBy;
$comments = $wpdb->get_results( $commentQ, ARRAY_A);
```

So far it works , but when i try to run 2 querys it fails.
What I wanna do is i want to run:

```
**SELECT *
FROM `wp_88_commentmeta`
ORDER BY `wp_88_commentmeta`.`meta_value` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30**
```

Im trying to get the meta_value only from that table.

So my question is , how can i call 2 querys in the same call, and if theres i a better way to do that?

**EDIT:**

I want to JOIN $wpdb->comments with commentmeta. Im only trying to get the field "meta_value".

```
    global $wpdb;
$commentQ = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments " . $whereClause . $orderBy;
$comments = $wpdb->get_results( $commentQ, ARRAY_A);

// build the string

$commentString = "";
$count = 0;
if( $comments ){
    $first = true;
    foreach( $comments as $row ){
        if( $first ){
            // column labels
            foreach ( $row as $col => $value ){
                    //$commentString .= $col . chr( 9 );
```

**After i join the tables i want to get "meta_value" from wp_commentmeta_88 and insert it instead of "comment_author"**

```
                    // Column Author
                if($col == 'comment_author') {
                $commentString .= 'User Meta        ';
                }           

            // Column IP
            if($col == 'comment_author_IP') {
                $commentString .= '   IP    ';
            }       

            // Column date
            if($col == 'comment_date') {
                $commentString .= '                Datum    ';
            }   

            // Column comment
            if($col == 'comment_content') {
                $commentString .= '                Meddelande   ';
            }                                           

            }
            $commentString .= chr( 13 );
            $first = false;
        }
```

Comment: Your second block of code does not demonstrate running two queries. It is just one query. Please provide enough code and commentary to explain the question properly.

Comment: Hi! I know my second block dont demonstrate how to run 2 queries. I gave that second block of code to show what query i want to run in the same way/time as the first.

Comment: But you don't even post how you ran the **first** query. Sounds like what you are asking is a pure SQL question. That is off topic here-- [faq]. If you explain what you are trying to accomplish there may be WordPress functions that will do it for you.

Comment: The first query im runing is a wordpress db query. Where im already running a working query. The secend "pure php query" is to show what query i want to run in the same way as the first, what i wanna do i to run them together.

Comment: If you are hoping to stack queries like `SELECT * FROM tableA; SELECT * FROM tableB;` I am pretty sure you can't. PHP/MySQL doesn't support it as far as I know, not on a LAMP stack anyway. I've heard rumors that you can do with if you have ASP.NET support. I don't work with that though.

Comment: hmmm... just found a function that apparently does allow that-- http://se2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Ahh i see...i cant use ASP.net thou. But did some research, check it i will edit the question with better information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to do this is SQL, use a subquery.

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT meta_value 
    FROM wp_commentmeta 
    WHERE meta_key = 'your-meta-key' 
    AND wp_commentmeta.comment_id = wp_comments.comment_ID LIMIT 1) as comment_author 
FROM wp_comments
```

Instead of the `*`, enumerate the fields you want but leave out `comment_author`. Obviously, `$wpdb` functions to keep the table names straight.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL keyword NATURAL RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT *  
  FROM table_name1 NATURAL RIGHT JOIN table_name2;
```

You can add WHERE, ORDER BY too